Convolutional Variational Autoencoder
I'm creating a Convolutional Variational Autoencoder with Tensorflow in Python code, with some images I created myself (64x64 pixels).
My problem is, that if I use anything else than Binary Crossentropy as my reconstruction loss, my model never converges, (the loss stays the same on all epochs), and I get all NaN predictions. Binary Crossentropy is obviously not the optimal loss function here. But nothing else works, for some bizare reason. I hope somebody can help me.
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, losses, optimizers, callbacks
import numpy as np

# Define input dimensions
input_shape = (64, 64, 3)  # Change to (64, 64, 1) if grayscale

# Encoder
def build_encoder(input_shape, latent_dim):
    encoder_inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder_inputs)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.Flatten()(x)
    #x = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
    #x = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name='z_mean')(x)
    z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name='z_log_var')(x)

    def sampling(args):
        z_mean, z_log_var = args
        batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
        dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
        epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
        return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon

    z = layers.Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,), name='z')([z_mean, z_log_var])

    encoder = models.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name='encoder')
    return encoder

# Decoder
def build_decoder(latent_dim):
    latent_inputs = layers.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
    #x = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(latent_inputs)
    #x = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.Dense(4 * 4 * 256, activation='relu')(latent_inputs)
    x = layers.Reshape((4, 4, 256))(x)
    x = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    decoder_outputs = layers.Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)  # 3 for color, change to 1 for grayscale

    decoder = models.Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs, name='decoder')
    return decoder

# Define the Variational Autoencoder (VAE) model
class VAE(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, **kwargs):
        super(VAE, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder

    def call(self, inputs):
        z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(inputs)
        reconstructed = self.decoder(z)
        kl_loss = -0.5 * tf.reduce_mean(
            z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var) + 1)
        kl_loss *= 0.0 #Sæt vægten her
        self.add_loss(kl_loss)
        return reconstructed

# Parameters
latent_dim = 50  # Adjust as needed

# Build encoder and decoder
encoder = build_encoder(input_shape, latent_dim)
decoder = build_decoder(latent_dim)

# Build VAE
vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
#vae.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=losses.MeanSquaredError())
vae.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=losses.BinaryCrossentropy())

optimizer.SGD 
# Print model summaries
encoder.summary()
decoder.summary()

# Ensure data shapes are correct before training
print(f"Shape of X_train: {X_train.shape}")
print(f"Shape of X_val: {X_val.shape}")

early_stopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=6, restore_best_weights=True)
reduce_lr = callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=3, min_lr=1e-4)

vae.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=30, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_val, X_val), callbacks=[early_stopping, reduce_lr])
vae.summary()

I have tried MSE, MAE, KLDiv loss and many others. All other loss functions gives NaN predictions and nothing converges.
I tried changing all hyperparameters I could think off. Nothing changes.
I looked everywhere on the internet for an answer, but no luck. I really hope somebody has an idea.

It's always hard to debug such an issue, but usually, such problem comes from the data. Have you normalized your data to avoid gradient explosion?

Hey, yeah, I normalized all pixel values to be between 0 and 1. Could there be other problems? My images are pretty simple ones. Not any crazy shapes.

def call(self, inputs):
z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(inputs)
reconstructed = self.decoder(z)
kl_loss = -0.5 * tf.reduce_mean(
z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var) + 1)
kl_loss *= 0.0 #Sæt vægten her
self.add_loss(kl_loss)
return reconstructed is that a typo?
